# Postrgresql looking for the wrong many to many table with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

**UPDATE: I found this:

"Active Record expects intermediate join tables to be named with a concatenation of the tables it joins, in alphabetical order."

Sigh...
**

I have 3 models: images, videos and keywords.  Images and videos look basically the same and I've been trying to do everything the same for them with regards to keywords.  But adding a keyword to an image works fine while adding a keyword to a video doesn't.

keyword.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :cases
has_and_belongs_to_many :images
has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
```

video.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords
```

image.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "images_keywords", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "image_id"
  t.integer  "keyword_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "videos_keywords", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "video_id"
  t.integer  "keyword_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

This works:

images_controller.rb

```
@image.keywords << Keyword.new(:word => "test")
```

This:

videos_controller.rb

```
@video.keywords << Keyword.new(:word => "test")
```

Gives me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in VideosController#create

PGError: ERROR:  relation "keywords_videos" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"keywords_videos"'::regclas...
                                    ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,      a.attnotnull
          FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
            ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
         WHERE a.attrelid = '"keywords_videos"'::regclass
           AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
         ORDER BY a.attnum
```

When I check the console for adding a keyword to an image, it correctly looks for "images_keywords"  Why does it look for "keywords_videos" for videos???

What is different about the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, the name of the join table needs to have the related models listed in alphabetical order, ie: `keywords_videos` not `videos_keywords`.